# How to exploit a CORS that only checks the end of the Origin header?

Tags: web-application

I noticed that in my website I only check that the Origin string ends with `"mysite.org"`. Meaning that for this request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.com
Origin: https://evil.com#mysite.org
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Authorization: bearer $TOK
```

will return as header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://evil.com#mysite.org
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Server: Apache/2

<RESPONSE>
```

The same behavior can be recreated with: `Origin: https://evil.com/mysite.org`, `Origin: https://evil.com?mysite.org` etc.

On paper this seems exploitable. But according to `https://developer.mozilla.org` the Origin header does not disclose the path. So how can an attacker create a malicious site `evil.com` in such a way that `xhr` requests has origin that ends with `site.org` ?

Or is this just a non exploitable flaw ?

Comment: the browser will ignore "allow-credentials" if wildcards are used in allowed-origins.

Answer (score 1):

If your site is `mysite.org` and you only check if the `Origin` header string ends with `mysite.org`, how about an attacker registering `someprefixtomysite.org`?

All conditions should work.